# Ошибка при указании соединения для controluser в конфигурации

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

[image: Error]

Прошу помощи у гуру MySQL. Такую вот ошибку выдает pma.
Что делать?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В снимках экрана ошибка "`Access denied for user root (using password: NO)`" и фигурирует "`controluser`".

Вам необходимо правильно установить имя пользователя и пароль для [`controluser`'а](https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/control_user). Они используются для соединения с [хранилищем конфигурации phpMyAdmin (configuration storage)](https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/pmadb), где хранятся настройки для дополнительный функций.

Хранилище конфигурации не обязательно, phpMyAdmin может работать без него. 
Поэтому у вас есть два пути:

- Выключить хранилище конфигурации: `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = null;` в [`config.inc.php`](https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/config.inc.php).
- [Настроить `controluser`'а](https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/control_user): создать пользователя в MySQL, предоставить ему определённый набор привилегий, затем добавить его имя и пароль в `config.inc.php`:

  ```
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = '<ИМЯ_ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ>';
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '<ПАРОЛЬ>';
  ```

Comment: дело в том, что через консоль я могу работать с базами данных, а вот pma не пускает.

Comment: И пользователя тоже создал в конфигурационном файле.

Comment: и пользователя задал не `root`, а ошибка все равно думает, что я `root`

Answer (score 1):

я выключил хранилище конфигурации, а потом обратно включил, помогло.